# How to implements generic dao for simple CRUD operation (Java EE, EJB injections)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, dao

I am currentlny in the process of refactoring my code and I noticed that I could use generic abstract class for CRUD operation. 
But ufortunately I am stuck right know.
The problem is, when I am injecting my DAO classes into Service classes I need to use remote interface of the entity(in my case Category), see the code below.

Remote interface for generic dao

```
public interface IGenericDaoRemote<T> {
void add(T t);
void remove(T t);
void update(T t);
List<T> getAll(Class<T> type);
}
```

Abstract class generic dao

```
@Stateless
@Remote(IGenericDaoRemote.class)
@Local(IGenericDaoLocal.class)
public abstract class GenericDao<T> implements IGenericDaoLocal<T>, IGenericDaoRemote<T> {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "postgresPersistant")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void add(T t) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.save(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T t) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.delete(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T t) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.update(t);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getAll(Class<T> type) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        return criteria.list();
    }
}
```

Example dao class:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(ICategoryDaoRemote.class)
@Local(ICategoryDaoLocal.class)
public class CategoryDao extends GenericDao<Category> implements ICategoryDaoRemote, ICategoryDaoLocal {
}
```

Service class:

```
@Stateless
@Local(ICategoryServiceLocal.class)
@Remote(ICategoryServiceRemote.class)
public class CategoryService implements ICategoryServiceRemote, ICategoryServiceLocal {

    @EJB
    private ICategoryDaoRemote categoryDao; // <-- here is a problem
.
.
.
}
```

As you can see, because I am using `ICategoryDaoRemote` interface as type of initialized variable I dont have access to the generic dao methods.
Am I missing something easy/basic?
Or is there any other way around to do this?

Have patience for my english please, I was trying my best!

Comment: `ICategoryDaoRemote` must extend `IGenericDaoRemote<Category>`.

Answer (score 0):

Di you really need remote? If you are not going to expose beans to some separate applications, just use **local** interfaces.

Not "the only difference". This is a huge difference.
You need remote only if you want to access EJB on one node from another node in the cluster. Or if you want to access EJB in one EAR from another EAR.

I suggest following:

1. Remove remote interface: definition of interface and references.
2. Define methods you need in the local interface.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, But even if I could, wouldnt the outcome be the same? The only difference would be the change in the  private ICategoryDaoLocal categoryDao;

Comment: You are right, but by a 'difference' I mean difference in current code, and that even if I could use local interface it wouldnt help to solve my problem, at least I think it wouldnt. And yes, I need Remote, I have multiple EJB projects, one EAR project that are working on jBoss app server, and is communicating with another app server, simple distributed system

Comment: If you really need remote interfaces, fine, then remove local interface. What you need local interface for?